# php string validation for basiclatin and 1supplement

Tags: php, regex

I have an xml schema where a description is defined like this:

```
[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}]{1,1000}
```

and i have to check in PHP that the user input string is valid for this encoding. Checking for the length is easy, but i don't find a way to use `preg_match` to check for basic latin. I've tried:

```
 preg_match('@^\p{IsBasicLatin}+@^\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}+$@u', $string);
```

but it says that there's an unknown property, even using basicLatin or Latin.

Comment: There is `\p{Latin}`. Try that against your strings. But it seems you may just use `preg_match('~^[\x00-\xFF]{1,1000}$~u', $s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `\p{IsBasicLatin}` stands for `[\x00-\x7F]` and `\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}` stands for `[\x80-\xFF]` (see [Unicode reference](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Code_Point_Ranges)).

Thus, all you need is

```
preg_match('~^[\x00-\xFF]{1,1000}$~u', $s)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/QHiyG6).

Comment: I've checked with some characters and this seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. Just check for the existence of either string:

```
<?php

$regex = '#(IsBasicLatin|IsLatin)#';
$string = '[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}]{1,1000}';

if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo 'Lorem Ipsum Shipmsum flipsum';
}
```

> Lorem Ipsum Shipmsum flipsum

See it here https://3v4l.org/P9RDu

Play with the regex here https://regex101.com/r/p56prj/1