# Find and wrap English characters inside Hebrew text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

> ## The problem

I have a large chunk of text in Hebrew (or any other language for that matter, except English).

Because the client is responsible for the input of all content sometimes he will sometimes enter English characters.

The website is in wordpress and the location where the client enters the text is the default content area, wysiwyg.

I need to find every English charcter/word and wrap it. Ignore English characters/words inside html tag "<>" and ignore &nbsp; and everything like this &gt; OR &copy, in this format &...;;

> ## Example text

```
<div class="content">
  <p>להאמית קרהשק this000 as well סכעיט דז מא, מנכם</p>
  <p>טיק מונופץ קליר, בנפת נפקט</p>
  <p>ת צשחמי צש בליא, מנסוטו צמלח</p>
  <p>סילקרגשח. <a href="http://google.com">ותלברו חשלו text וחאית נו</a> עמחליף לורם איפסום</p>
  <p>בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט more text here ליבם סולגק</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

> ## Final result

Find and wrap every match with a span tag,

```
<p>להאמית קרהשק this000 as well סכעיט דז מא, מנכם</p>
```

Will become

```
<p>להאמית קרהשק <span class="en">this000 as well</span> סכעיט דז מא, מנכם</p>
```

And so on

> ## My solution

```
<script>
const to_english_regex = /(?<!<[^>]*)([0-9]+)?[a-z_-]+([0-9\s_-]+)?[a-z_-]+([0-9]+)?/ig

$('.to-english').html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(to_english_regex, '<span style="font-family: futura;">$&</span>');
});
</script>
```

This seems to ignore all English inside the tags but not ignores &...; type of code.

Alos seems like this `(?<!<[^>]*)` part causes the problems in IOS devices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const to_english_regex = /(?<!<[^>]*)([0-9]+)?[a-z_-]+([0-9\s_-]+)?[a-z_-]+([0-9]+)?/ig



let html = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML
        
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Result:<br><pre>" + html.replace(to_english_regex, '<span style="font-family: futura;">$&</span>') + "</pre>";
```

```css
#result {background-color: lightblue;}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>להאמית קרהשק this000 as well סכעיט דז מא, מנכם</p>
  <p>טיק מונופץ קליר, בנפת נפקט</p>
  <p>ת צשחמי צש בליא, מנסוטו צמלח</p>
  <p>סילקרגשח. <a href="http://google.com">ותלברו חשלו text וחאית נו</a> עמחליף לורם איפסום</p>
  <p>בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט more text here ליבם סולגק</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Try something like ``text.replace(/(<[^>]+>|&#?\w+;)|(?!\s)[A-Za-z0-9\p{P}\p{S}\s]+(?<!\s)/ug, (x,y) => y || `<span style="font-family: futura;">${x}</span>` )``

Comment: Do you mean find "latin characters"?  Because no (sensible) regex will find "English" text without a dictionary.

Comment: Did you have a chance to test my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning to use this on iOS devices, it seems you can't rely on the latest ECMAScript standards and have to comply with the older sepcifications. I understand [ES6](https://caniuse.com/?search=es6) is in play here.

You can use

```js
const punct = "!-/:-@[-`{-~\\u00A1-\\u00A9\\u00AB\\u00AC\\u00AE-\\u00B1\\u00B4\\u00B6-\\u00B8\\u00BB\\u00BF\\u00D7\\u00F7\\u02C2-\\u02C5\\u02D2-\\u02DF\\u02E5-\\u02EB\\u02ED\\u02EF-\\u02FF\\u0375\\u037E\\u0384\\u0385\\u0387\\u03F6\\u0482\\u055A-\\u055F\\u0589\\u058A\\u058D-\\u058F\\u05BE\\u05C0\\u05C3\\u05C6\\u05F3\\u05F4\\u0606-\\u060F\\u061B\\u061E\\u061F\\u066A-\\u066D\\u06D4\\u06DE\\u06E9\\u06FD\\u06FE\\u0700-\\u070D\\u07F6-\\u07F9\\u07FE\\u07FF\\u0830-\\u083E\\u085E\\u0964\\u0965\\u0970\\u09F2\\u09F3\\u09FA\\u09FB\\u09FD\\u0A76\\u0AF0\\u0AF1\\u0B70\\u0BF3-\\u0BFA\\u0C7F\\u0C84\\u0D4F\\u0D79\\u0DF4\\u0E3F\\u0E4F\\u0E5A\\u0E5B\\u0F01-\\u0F17\\u0F1A-\\u0F1F\\u0F34\\u0F36\\u0F38\\u0F3A-\\u0F3D\\u0F85\\u0FBE-\\u0FC5\\u0FC7-\\u0FCC\\u0FCE-\\u0FDA\\u104A-\\u104F\\u109E\\u109F\\u10FB\\u1360-\\u1368\\u1390-\\u1399\\u1400\\u166D\\u166E\\u169B\\u169C\\u16EB-\\u16ED\\u1735\\u1736\\u17D4-\\u17D6\\u17D8-\\u17DB\\u1800-\\u180A\\u1940\\u1944\\u1945\\u19DE-\\u19FF\\u1A1E\\u1A1F\\u1AA0-\\u1AA6\\u1AA8-\\u1AAD\\u1B5A-\\u1B6A\\u1B74-\\u1B7C\\u1BFC-\\u1BFF\\u1C3B-\\u1C3F\\u1C7E\\u1C7F\\u1CC0-\\u1CC7\\u1CD3\\u1FBD\\u1FBF-\\u1FC1\\u1FCD-\\u1FCF\\u1FDD-\\u1FDF\\u1FED-\\u1FEF\\u1FFD\\u1FFE\\u2010-\\u2027\\u2030-\\u205E\\u207A-\\u207E\\u208A-\\u208E\\u20A0-\\u20BF\\u2100\\u2101\\u2103-\\u2106\\u2108\\u2109\\u2114\\u2116-\\u2118\\u211E-\\u2123\\u2125\\u2127\\u2129\\u212E\\u213A\\u213B\\u2140-\\u2144\\u214A-\\u214D\\u214F\\u218A\\u218B\\u2190-\\u2426\\u2440-\\u244A\\u249C-\\u24E9\\u2500-\\u2775\\u2794-\\u2B73\\u2B76-\\u2B95\\u2B98-\\u2BC8\\u2BCA-\\u2BFE\\u2CE5-\\u2CEA\\u2CF9-\\u2CFC\\u2CFE\\u2CFF\\u2D70\\u2E00-\\u2E2E\\u2E30-\\u2E4E\\u2E80-\\u2E99\\u2E9B-\\u2EF3\\u2F00-\\u2FD5\\u2FF0-\\u2FFB\\u3001-\\u3004\\u3008-\\u3020\\u3030\\u3036\\u3037\\u303D-\\u303F\\u309B\\u309C\\u30A0\\u30FB\\u3190\\u3191\\u3196-\\u319F\\u31C0-\\u31E3\\u3200-\\u321E\\u322A-\\u3247\\u3250\\u3260-\\u327F\\u328A-\\u32B0\\u32C0-\\u32FE\\u3300-\\u33FF\\u4DC0-\\u4DFF\\uA490-\\uA4C6\\uA4FE\\uA4FF\\uA60D-\\uA60F\\uA673\\uA67E\\uA6F2-\\uA6F7\\uA700-\\uA716\\uA720\\uA721\\uA789\\uA78A\\uA828-\\uA82B\\uA836-\\uA839\\uA874-\\uA877\\uA8CE\\uA8CF\\uA8F8-\\uA8FA\\uA8FC\\uA92E\\uA92F\\uA95F\\uA9C1-\\uA9CD\\uA9DE\\uA9DF\\uAA5C-\\uAA5F\\uAA77-\\uAA79\\uAADE\\uAADF\\uAAF0\\uAAF1\\uAB5B\\uABEB\\uFB29\\uFBB2-\\uFBC1\\uFD3E\\uFD3F\\uFDFC\\uFDFD\\uFE10-\\uFE19\\uFE30-\\uFE52\\uFE54-\\uFE66\\uFE68-\\uFE6B\\uFF01-\\uFF0F\\uFF1A-\\uFF20\\uFF3B-\\uFF40\\uFF5B-\\uFF65\\uFFE0-\\uFFE6\\uFFE8-\\uFFEE\\uFFFC\\uFFFD\\u{10100}-\\u{10102}\\u{10137}-\\u{1013F}\\u{10179}-\\u{10189}\\u{1018C}-\\u{1018E}\\u{10190}-\\u{1019B}\\u{101A0}\\u{101D0}-\\u{101FC}\\u{1039F}\\u{103D0}\\u{1056F}\\u{10857}\\u{10877}\\u{10878}\\u{1091F}\\u{1093F}\\u{10A50}-\\u{10A58}\\u{10A7F}\\u{10AC8}\\u{10AF0}-\\u{10AF6}\\u{10B39}-\\u{10B3F}\\u{10B99}-\\u{10B9C}\\u{10F55}-\\u{10F59}\\u{11047}-\\u{1104D}\\u{110BB}\\u{110BC}\\u{110BE}-\\u{110C1}\\u{11140}-\\u{11143}\\u{11174}\\u{11175}\\u{111C5}-\\u{111C8}\\u{111CD}\\u{111DB}\\u{111DD}-\\u{111DF}\\u{11238}-\\u{1123D}\\u{112A9}\\u{1144B}-\\u{1144F}\\u{1145B}\\u{1145D}\\u{114C6}\\u{115C1}-\\u{115D7}\\u{11641}-\\u{11643}\\u{11660}-\\u{1166C}\\u{1173C}-\\u{1173F}\\u{1183B}\\u{11A3F}-\\u{11A46}\\u{11A9A}-\\u{11A9C}\\u{11A9E}-\\u{11AA2}\\u{11C41}-\\u{11C45}\\u{11C70}\\u{11C71}\\u{11EF7}\\u{11EF8}\\u{12470}-\\u{12474}\\u{16A6E}\\u{16A6F}\\u{16AF5}\\u{16B37}-\\u{16B3F}\\u{16B44}\\u{16B45}\\u{16E97}-\\u{16E9A}\\u{1BC9C}\\u{1BC9F}\\u{1D000}-\\u{1D0F5}\\u{1D100}-\\u{1D126}\\u{1D129}-\\u{1D164}\\u{1D16A}-\\u{1D16C}\\u{1D183}\\u{1D184}\\u{1D18C}-\\u{1D1A9}\\u{1D1AE}-\\u{1D1E8}\\u{1D200}-\\u{1D241}\\u{1D245}\\u{1D300}-\\u{1D356}\\u{1D6C1}\\u{1D6DB}\\u{1D6FB}\\u{1D715}\\u{1D735}\\u{1D74F}\\u{1D76F}\\u{1D789}\\u{1D7A9}\\u{1D7C3}\\u{1D800}-\\u{1D9FF}\\u{1DA37}-\\u{1DA3A}\\u{1DA6D}-\\u{1DA74}\\u{1DA76}-\\u{1DA83}\\u{1DA85}-\\u{1DA8B}\\u{1E95E}\\u{1E95F}\\u{1ECAC}\\u{1ECB0}\\u{1EEF0}\\u{1EEF1}\\u{1F000}-\\u{1F02B}\\u{1F030}-\\u{1F093}\\u{1F0A0}-\\u{1F0AE}\\u{1F0B1}-\\u{1F0BF}\\u{1F0C1}-\\u{1F0CF}\\u{1F0D1}-\\u{1F0F5}\\u{1F110}-\\u{1F16B}\\u{1F170}-\\u{1F1AC}\\u{1F1E6}-\\u{1F202}\\u{1F210}-\\u{1F23B}\\u{1F240}-\\u{1F248}\\u{1F250}\\u{1F251}\\u{1F260}-\\u{1F265}\\u{1F300}-\\u{1F6D4}\\u{1F6E0}-\\u{1F6EC}\\u{1F6F0}-\\u{1F6F9}\\u{1F700}-\\u{1F773}\\u{1F780}-\\u{1F7D8}\\u{1F800}-\\u{1F80B}\\u{1F810}-\\u{1F847}\\u{1F850}-\\u{1F859}\\u{1F860}-\\u{1F887}\\u{1F890}-\\u{1F8AD}\\u{1F900}-\\u{1F90B}\\u{1F910}-\\u{1F93E}\\u{1F940}-\\u{1F970}\\u{1F973}-\\u{1F976}\\u{1F97A}\\u{1F97C}-\\u{1F9A2}\\u{1F9B0}-\\u{1F9B9}\\u{1F9C0}-\\u{1F9C2}\\u{1F9D0}-\\u{1F9FF}\\u{1FA60}-\\u{1FA6D}";
const to_english_regex = new RegExp("(<[^>]+>|&#?\\w+;)|[A-Za-z0-9" + punct + "\\s]+", "ug");
html = html.replace(to_english_regex, (x,y) => y || '<span style="font-family: futura;">'+x+'</span>' );
```

**NOTE**: If you want to keep [all Latin chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043409/php-string-validation-for-basiclatin-and-1supplement/53043622#53043622), replace the regex to

```js
const to_english_regex = new RegExp("(<[^>]+>|&#?\\w+;)|[\\x00-\xFF" + punct + "\\s]+", "ug");
```

**Regex details**

- `(<[^>]+>|&#?\w+;)` - Group 1: `<`, one or more chars other than `>`, `>`, or `&` followed with an optional `#` and then one or more word chars and a `;`
- `|` - or
- `[A-Za-z0-9 + punct + \s]+` - one or more ASCII letters or digits, any Unicode punctuation and whitespaces.

If Group 1 matches, put it back, else, wrap the whole match value with the span tag.

The whole code will look like

```js
const punct = "!-/:-@[-`{-~\\u00A1-\\u00A9\\u00AB\\u00AC\\u00AE-\\u00B1\\u00B4\\u00B6-\\u00B8\\u00BB\\u00BF\\u00D7\\u00F7\\u02C2-\\u02C5\\u02D2-\\u02DF\\u02E5-\\u02EB\\u02ED\\u02EF-\\u02FF\\u0375\\u037E\\u0384\\u0385\\u0387\\u03F6\\u0482\\u055A-\\u055F\\u0589\\u058A\\u058D-\\u058F\\u05BE\\u05C0\\u05C3\\u05C6\\u05F3\\u05F4\\u0606-\\u060F\\u061B\\u061E\\u061F\\u066A-\\u066D\\u06D4\\u06DE\\u06E9\\u06FD\\u06FE\\u0700-\\u070D\\u07F6-\\u07F9\\u07FE\\u07FF\\u0830-\\u083E\\u085E\\u0964\\u0965\\u0970\\u09F2\\u09F3\\u09FA\\u09FB\\u09FD\\u0A76\\u0AF0\\u0AF1\\u0B70\\u0BF3-\\u0BFA\\u0C7F\\u0C84\\u0D4F\\u0D79\\u0DF4\\u0E3F\\u0E4F\\u0E5A\\u0E5B\\u0F01-\\u0F17\\u0F1A-\\u0F1F\\u0F34\\u0F36\\u0F38\\u0F3A-\\u0F3D\\u0F85\\u0FBE-\\u0FC5\\u0FC7-\\u0FCC\\u0FCE-\\u0FDA\\u104A-\\u104F\\u109E\\u109F\\u10FB\\u1360-\\u1368\\u1390-\\u1399\\u1400\\u166D\\u166E\\u169B\\u169C\\u16EB-\\u16ED\\u1735\\u1736\\u17D4-\\u17D6\\u17D8-\\u17DB\\u1800-\\u180A\\u1940\\u1944\\u1945\\u19DE-\\u19FF\\u1A1E\\u1A1F\\u1AA0-\\u1AA6\\u1AA8-\\u1AAD\\u1B5A-\\u1B6A\\u1B74-\\u1B7C\\u1BFC-\\u1BFF\\u1C3B-\\u1C3F\\u1C7E\\u1C7F\\u1CC0-\\u1CC7\\u1CD3\\u1FBD\\u1FBF-\\u1FC1\\u1FCD-\\u1FCF\\u1FDD-\\u1FDF\\u1FED-\\u1FEF\\u1FFD\\u1FFE\\u2010-\\u2027\\u2030-\\u205E\\u207A-\\u207E\\u208A-\\u208E\\u20A0-\\u20BF\\u2100\\u2101\\u2103-\\u2106\\u2108\\u2109\\u2114\\u2116-\\u2118\\u211E-\\u2123\\u2125\\u2127\\u2129\\u212E\\u213A\\u213B\\u2140-\\u2144\\u214A-\\u214D\\u214F\\u218A\\u218B\\u2190-\\u2426\\u2440-\\u244A\\u249C-\\u24E9\\u2500-\\u2775\\u2794-\\u2B73\\u2B76-\\u2B95\\u2B98-\\u2BC8\\u2BCA-\\u2BFE\\u2CE5-\\u2CEA\\u2CF9-\\u2CFC\\u2CFE\\u2CFF\\u2D70\\u2E00-\\u2E2E\\u2E30-\\u2E4E\\u2E80-\\u2E99\\u2E9B-\\u2EF3\\u2F00-\\u2FD5\\u2FF0-\\u2FFB\\u3001-\\u3004\\u3008-\\u3020\\u3030\\u3036\\u3037\\u303D-\\u303F\\u309B\\u309C\\u30A0\\u30FB\\u3190\\u3191\\u3196-\\u319F\\u31C0-\\u31E3\\u3200-\\u321E\\u322A-\\u3247\\u3250\\u3260-\\u327F\\u328A-\\u32B0\\u32C0-\\u32FE\\u3300-\\u33FF\\u4DC0-\\u4DFF\\uA490-\\uA4C6\\uA4FE\\uA4FF\\uA60D-\\uA60F\\uA673\\uA67E\\uA6F2-\\uA6F7\\uA700-\\uA716\\uA720\\uA721\\uA789\\uA78A\\uA828-\\uA82B\\uA836-\\uA839\\uA874-\\uA877\\uA8CE\\uA8CF\\uA8F8-\\uA8FA\\uA8FC\\uA92E\\uA92F\\uA95F\\uA9C1-\\uA9CD\\uA9DE\\uA9DF\\uAA5C-\\uAA5F\\uAA77-\\uAA79\\uAADE\\uAADF\\uAAF0\\uAAF1\\uAB5B\\uABEB\\uFB29\\uFBB2-\\uFBC1\\uFD3E\\uFD3F\\uFDFC\\uFDFD\\uFE10-\\uFE19\\uFE30-\\uFE52\\uFE54-\\uFE66\\uFE68-\\uFE6B\\uFF01-\\uFF0F\\uFF1A-\\uFF20\\uFF3B-\\uFF40\\uFF5B-\\uFF65\\uFFE0-\\uFFE6\\uFFE8-\\uFFEE\\uFFFC\\uFFFD\\u{10100}-\\u{10102}\\u{10137}-\\u{1013F}\\u{10179}-\\u{10189}\\u{1018C}-\\u{1018E}\\u{10190}-\\u{1019B}\\u{101A0}\\u{101D0}-\\u{101FC}\\u{1039F}\\u{103D0}\\u{1056F}\\u{10857}\\u{10877}\\u{10878}\\u{1091F}\\u{1093F}\\u{10A50}-\\u{10A58}\\u{10A7F}\\u{10AC8}\\u{10AF0}-\\u{10AF6}\\u{10B39}-\\u{10B3F}\\u{10B99}-\\u{10B9C}\\u{10F55}-\\u{10F59}\\u{11047}-\\u{1104D}\\u{110BB}\\u{110BC}\\u{110BE}-\\u{110C1}\\u{11140}-\\u{11143}\\u{11174}\\u{11175}\\u{111C5}-\\u{111C8}\\u{111CD}\\u{111DB}\\u{111DD}-\\u{111DF}\\u{11238}-\\u{1123D}\\u{112A9}\\u{1144B}-\\u{1144F}\\u{1145B}\\u{1145D}\\u{114C6}\\u{115C1}-\\u{115D7}\\u{11641}-\\u{11643}\\u{11660}-\\u{1166C}\\u{1173C}-\\u{1173F}\\u{1183B}\\u{11A3F}-\\u{11A46}\\u{11A9A}-\\u{11A9C}\\u{11A9E}-\\u{11AA2}\\u{11C41}-\\u{11C45}\\u{11C70}\\u{11C71}\\u{11EF7}\\u{11EF8}\\u{12470}-\\u{12474}\\u{16A6E}\\u{16A6F}\\u{16AF5}\\u{16B37}-\\u{16B3F}\\u{16B44}\\u{16B45}\\u{16E97}-\\u{16E9A}\\u{1BC9C}\\u{1BC9F}\\u{1D000}-\\u{1D0F5}\\u{1D100}-\\u{1D126}\\u{1D129}-\\u{1D164}\\u{1D16A}-\\u{1D16C}\\u{1D183}\\u{1D184}\\u{1D18C}-\\u{1D1A9}\\u{1D1AE}-\\u{1D1E8}\\u{1D200}-\\u{1D241}\\u{1D245}\\u{1D300}-\\u{1D356}\\u{1D6C1}\\u{1D6DB}\\u{1D6FB}\\u{1D715}\\u{1D735}\\u{1D74F}\\u{1D76F}\\u{1D789}\\u{1D7A9}\\u{1D7C3}\\u{1D800}-\\u{1D9FF}\\u{1DA37}-\\u{1DA3A}\\u{1DA6D}-\\u{1DA74}\\u{1DA76}-\\u{1DA83}\\u{1DA85}-\\u{1DA8B}\\u{1E95E}\\u{1E95F}\\u{1ECAC}\\u{1ECB0}\\u{1EEF0}\\u{1EEF1}\\u{1F000}-\\u{1F02B}\\u{1F030}-\\u{1F093}\\u{1F0A0}-\\u{1F0AE}\\u{1F0B1}-\\u{1F0BF}\\u{1F0C1}-\\u{1F0CF}\\u{1F0D1}-\\u{1F0F5}\\u{1F110}-\\u{1F16B}\\u{1F170}-\\u{1F1AC}\\u{1F1E6}-\\u{1F202}\\u{1F210}-\\u{1F23B}\\u{1F240}-\\u{1F248}\\u{1F250}\\u{1F251}\\u{1F260}-\\u{1F265}\\u{1F300}-\\u{1F6D4}\\u{1F6E0}-\\u{1F6EC}\\u{1F6F0}-\\u{1F6F9}\\u{1F700}-\\u{1F773}\\u{1F780}-\\u{1F7D8}\\u{1F800}-\\u{1F80B}\\u{1F810}-\\u{1F847}\\u{1F850}-\\u{1F859}\\u{1F860}-\\u{1F887}\\u{1F890}-\\u{1F8AD}\\u{1F900}-\\u{1F90B}\\u{1F910}-\\u{1F93E}\\u{1F940}-\\u{1F970}\\u{1F973}-\\u{1F976}\\u{1F97A}\\u{1F97C}-\\u{1F9A2}\\u{1F9B0}-\\u{1F9B9}\\u{1F9C0}-\\u{1F9C2}\\u{1F9D0}-\\u{1F9FF}\\u{1FA60}-\\u{1FA6D}";
const to_english_regex = new RegExp("(<[^>]+>|&#?\\w+;)|[A-Za-z0-9" + punct + "\\s]+", "ug");

let html = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Result:<br><pre>" + html.replace(to_english_regex, (x,y) => y || '<span style="font-family: futura;">'+x+'</span>' ) + "</pre>";
```

```css
#result {background-color: lightblue;}
span {color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>להאמית קרהשק this000 as well סכעיט דז מא, מנכם</p>
  <p>טיק מונופץ קליר, בנפת נפקט</p>
  <p>ת צשחמי צש בליא, מנסוטו צמלח</p>
  <p>סילקרגשח. <a href="http://google.com">ותלברו חשלו text וחאית נו</a> עמחליף לורם איפסום</p>
  <p>בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט more text here ליבם סולגק</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
```